# PhpStorm can not parse PHPUnit version output. Very strange error

Tags: php, windows, vagrant, phpunit, phpstorm

I'm trying to set up PHPUnit in PhpStorm 2017.1 on Windows 10 using a Vagrant box for a Laravel project. I've set up a remote interpreter, and I've been using it for a couple of months now, everything working fine.

I've been asked to do some unit testing so I've set up PhpStorm with PHPUnit, following my coworkers' instructions (PhpStorm on Mac) but when I select `autoload.php` in my vendor folder I receive the error message

> "Can not parse PHPUnit version output: Could not open input file: `/vagrant/vendorphpunitphpunitphpunit`" (no slashes).

If I run PHPUnit via `vagrant ssh` in the command line, my tests execute fine, and I can manually select the PHPUnit phar in PhpStorm, but then I'm missing the autoloaded classes, so everything fails.

[image: Screenshot of PhpStorm's PHPUnit config]

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-35806 I guess

Comment: Seems to be back since WSL integration was introduced this November

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[WI-35806](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-35806) -- seems the same. It was marked as fixed today.

If that's the right ticket then the fix should be available in **2017.1.2** -- you may try [EAP build](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Early+Access+Program) when it will become available if you cannot wait until 2017.1.2 final will be officially released.

Answer (score 5):

If you get a similar bug when setting up PHPUnit with Docker, then it could also be because of bad volume bindings.

In the following preferences screen, click on the folder icon to `Edit Docker Container Settings`, then edit the `Volume bindings`.

[image]

Comment: Awesome! This hint solved my problem with the path configuration.

Comment: setting mine to /var/www/html fixed

Answer (score 0):

In case you configure remote PHP cli interpreter by `Docker Compose`, if you get a similar bug of parsing PHPUnit version output like this, the reason may comes from using `variables` in `docker-compose.yaml` (e.g using `$PWD` in `volume binding`).

For instance, if you mount your current directory like this:

```
...
  volumes:
    - $PWD:/var/www/html
```

PHPStorm do not know what `$PWD` really is, therefore it cannot parse PHPUnit output due to `volume binding`. You should change the variables to a specific value (e.g to `./` in this case):

```
...
  volumes:
    - ./:/var/www/html
```

Comment: PHPStorm doesn't read your docker-compose for this information and as soon as you run the docker compose file, it expands that parameter to an absolute path.

Comment: This is an old question so I guess things have changed but the latest phpstorm version (build  #PS-221.5787.33) does not expand shell variables in volume bindings. Hence, changing `$PWD` to `.` fixed the issue